# Flutter Sort list by 3 properties

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List with some properties and I would like two sort all of them by three properties. In my list I have **number**, **number2**, **date** and some other properties. When I click on **number** list sort by **number** ***ASC***, when I click again on **number** list sort ***DESC*** by **number**. When I click again on **number**, do not sort by **number**. Same for **number2** and **date**. But When I click on **number** and then on **number2**, sort by **both** fields. Same for **date**

I tried like this but does not work for me.

All fields are ***ASC*** order

```
reports.sort((a, b) => <Comparator<Reports>>[
                    (o1, o2) => o1.number.compareTo(o2.number),
                    (o1, o2) => o1.number2.compareTo(o2.number2),
                    (o1, o2) => o1.date.compareTo(o2.date),
                  ].map((e) => e(a, b)).firstWhere((e) => e != 0, orElse: () => 0));
```

`Number` field is ***DASC*** order other are ***ASC*** order

```
reports.sort((a, b) => <Comparator<Reports>>[
                    (o1, o2) => o2.number.compareTo(o1.number),
                    (o1, o2) => o1.number2.compareTo(o2.number2),
                    (o1, o2) => o1.date.compareTo(o2.date),
                  ].map((e) => e(a, b)).firstWhere((e) => e != 0, orElse: () => 0));
```

Tried like this but does not work. If anyone have idea please help.

Comment: can you create a simple code example with your list and how should looks final result?